# Populating table layout from database

Tags: android

I am a beginner & my objective is to create a table in which data should be populated  from database according to  my query. How can I do it?I searched in google, but couldn't find much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just design the Table layout using views. 
Then from database get all the values like in form of a cursor. 
Then write loop for cursor until it ll reach to the end record.  and within that loop u just assign values to views which are present in TableLayout.